# How is process priority calculated?

Tags: linux, process, priority

Can someone explain how "real" process priority (i.e. `pri_baz` field of `ps`) is calculated?

My guess is:

```
pri_baz = 99 - static_priority  # if static_priority > 0 (real-time process)
pri_baz = 100 + min(20 + nice + dynamic_adjustment, 39)  # if static_priority = 0 (time-shared process)
```

This is supported by the following test:

```
# chrt -r 1 sleep 1 \
> & chrt -r 99 sleep 1 \
> & nice --20 sleep 1 \
> & nice -19 sleep 1 \
> & ps -C sleep -O pri_baz
[1] 25408
[2] 25409
[3] 25410
[4] 25411
   PID BAZ S TTY          TIME COMMAND
 25408  98 S pts/3    00:00:00 sleep 1
 25409   0 S pts/3    00:00:00 sleep 1
 25410 100 S pts/3    00:00:00 sleep 1
 25411 139 S pts/3    00:00:00 sleep 1
```

However I'm puzzled because:

1. `pri_baz` = 99 appears to be unused.
2. I knew Linux handled (by default) 140 priority queues, and this scheme gives only 139 values of priority.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `ps`’s output, [`pri_baz` is calculated as](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/6164fbb82916178a0fa60f4eb1f7b651247407df/ps/output.c#L658) `pp->priority + 100`, and `pp->priority` is the `prio` value from the kernel. This is [described as](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.4/source/include/linux/sched/prio.h#L10)

> Priority of a process goes from 0..`MAX_PRIO`-1, valid RT
>   priority is 0..`MAX_RT_PRIO`-1, and `SCHED_NORMAL`/`SCHED_BATCH`
>   tasks are in the range `MAX_RT_PRIO`..`MAX_PRIO`-1. Priority
>   values are inverted: lower `p->prio` value means higher priority.
>
> The `MAX_USER_RT_PRIO` value allows the actual maximum
>   RT priority to be separate from the value exported to
>   user-space.  This allows kernel threads to set their
>   priority to a value higher than any user task. Note:
>   `MAX_RT_PRIO` must not be smaller than `MAX_USER_RT_PRIO`.

So the range in the kernel does cover 140 values, from 0 to `MAX_PRIO`–1 (139).

However, [the minimum FIFO and RT priority is 1](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.4/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L5839), and this explains the missing value: the input values (at least, that can be set from userspace, using [`sched_setscheduler`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html)) go from 1 to 99, and the kernel [converts those to `prio` values using the formula](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.4/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L1360) `MAX_RT_PRIO` – 1 – *priority*, giving values from 0 to 98.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this (not an expert). I see 0 and 139, this suggests a range of at least 140. I see you setting real time priority to 1 and 99, but see it reported as 0 and 98. I see the nice of a range of 40, both for what you asked for, and what is reported. So may be some -1 involved. But I see nothing special about 99.

The highest it can set with `chrt -r` is 99. This reports as 98.

It looks like someone made an out-by-one-error in the implementation some-where.

Comment: Just counting from 0...